# how to solve this system of differential equations numerically?

Tags: differential-equations

[system of differential equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO1BZ.png)

Pls look at an image above

How can i build up the derivation function for this system to use scipy.integrate.odeint?
I tried to express 3 DEs as linear combinations of second derivatives of coordinates(q,alpha,beta) and calculate them in derivation function(taken by odeint) with first or non derivative terms. 
But I found that the coefficient matrix has degeneracy and got some trouble.
How can I solve this kind of system?

Answer (score 0):

You have a system

```
M(z)*D*z'' = F(t,z,z')
```

You can implement it using the linear systems solvers of numpy

```py
def system(t,u):
    z,Dz = np.reshape(u,[-1,2])
    D2z = diag([1,1/q,1/b]).dot( np.linalg.solve(M(z), F(t,z,Dz)) )
    return np.concatenate(Dz, D2z)
```

or similar.